# Renaming multiple columns and gathering with dplyr in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to find a convenient way to rename multiple columns using the tidyverse. Say I have a tibble

```
df <- tibble(a = 1, b = 2, tmp_2000 = 23, tmp_2001 = 22.1, tmp_2002 = 25, pre_2000, pre_2001, pre_2002)

# A tibble: 1 x 8
  a     b tmp_2000 tmp_2001 tmp_2002 pre_2000 pre_2001 pre_2002
<dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
  1     2       23     22.1       25      100      103      189
```

`temp` and `pre` stand for temperature and precipitations. I want to reorganize this table in a tidy form, i.e. with one column for `temperature`, one for `precipitations`, and each row is the corresponding value for the year.

Right now the only option I found was to do something like this

```
df <- df %>%
  select(-starts_with("pre"))

names(df)[3:5] <- substr(names(df)[3:5],5,8) 

df<-df %>%
  gather(`2000`:`2002`,key = "year",value="temp")  %>%
  mutate("year" = as.integer(year)) 

# A tibble: 3 x 4
  a     b  year  temp
<dbl> <dbl> <int> <dbl>
  1     2  2000  23  
  1     2  2001  22.1
  1     2  2002  25
```

This is not fantastic as I need to do the same thing with precipitations and then joins the two tables. In  the future I will be getting more weather variables and this process will quickly become a pain.

Does anyone have an idea on how to do this more efficiently using the tidyverse?

Thanks,

Jo

PS: the only similar posts I saw referred to recoding the variables (using mutate_at), or renaming columns using the `names` that I showed above.

Comment: `reshape(df,3:ncol(df),sep="_",dir="long")`

Comment: Onyambu this didn't work, I get `Warning messages:
1: Setting row names on a tibble is deprecated. 
2: Setting row names on a tibble is deprecated. 
3: Setting row names on a tibble is deprecated. `

Comment: the warning is because you have a `tibble` nothing more. ie you can do `reshape(data.frame(df),3:ncol(df),idvar = 1:2,sep="_",dir="long")` and then set the `rownames` to NULL

Comment: Ok thanks. More concise than the tidyverse but less readable.

Comment: What do you mean by less readable? I guess maybe its because the function `reshape` is new to you?? I cant tell.. You can perhaps use `data.table::melt`

Comment: yes I'm doing all my reshaping with `dplyr::` so `reshape` seems exotic, I'm sure with some practice it will become obivous. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
    gather(measure, value, -a, -b) %>% 
    separate(measure, into = c("type", "year"), sep = "_") %>% 
    mutate(type = case_when(type == "tmp" ~ "temp", type == "pre" ~ "precip")) %>% 
    spread(type, value)
#       a     b year  precip  temp
# 1     1     2 2000     100  23  
# 2     1     2 2001     103  22.1
# 3     1     2 2002     189  25
```

We first gather all of the data in long format, then we separate the year from the measurement, then we change the names of the measurements, and lastly we spread the data back to wide format.

Comment: Thank you AndS., that does the job perfectly and is really elegant.

Answer (score 2):

```
data.frame(df)%>%
   reshape(3:ncol(df),sep="_",dir="long")%>%
   `rownames<-`(NULL)
  a b time  tmp pre id
1 1 2 2000 23.0 100  1
2 1 2 2001 22.1 103  1
3 1 2 2002 25.0 189  1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df <- tibble(
  a = 1,
  b = 2,
  tmp_2000 = 23,
  tmp_2001 = 22.1,
  tmp_2002 = 25,
  pre_2000=100,
  pre_2001=103,
  pre_2002=189
)


df %>% 
  gather(key, value, -a:-b) %>% 
  separate(key, c("type", "year")) %>% 
  spread(type, value= value )

#> # A tibble: 3 x 5
#>       a     b year    pre   tmp
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     1     2 2000    100  23  
#> 2     1     2 2001    103  22.1
#> 3     1     2 2002    189  25
```

```